# How to adjust the layout when the button text changes programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I've got some button in an horizontal layout (see 1st picture). When I change its text (programmatically), android trys to adjust them, but sometimes the result is horrible (see 2nd picture).
I would like that the last button was another line, but I have not succeeded. (see 3rd picture)

[image]

Comment: Do you have fixed no of Data to show?

Comment: You should edit your layout with all the possible "edge cases" in your texts. When you get to ONE layout that is good for all possibilities, then you're done. Now you use this layout, and android will take care of moving the widgets around according to the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. The key is use a TextView and make its text SpannableStrings:
This is the code:

The interface:

```
public interface IClickSpannableListener {
  void onClickSpanText(SpecialClickableSpan sender);
}
```

The class:

```
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.View;

public class SpecialClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    private IClickSpannableListener oyente;
    private String text;
    private RoundedBackgroundSpan roundedBackgroundSpan;

    //region get    
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public RoundedBackgroundSpan getRoundedBackgroundSpan() {
        return roundedBackgroundSpan;
    }
    //endregion

    //region constructor
    public SpecialClickableSpan(String text,IClickSpannableListener quien,boolean isRoundedBackgroundSpam){
        super();
        //IMPORTANT: Replace space (alt + 255) by asc 32.
        this.text = text.replace(' ',' '); 
        if (isRoundedBackgroundSpam){
            roundedBackgroundSpan=new RoundedBackgroundSpan();
        }
        oyente =quien;
    }
    //endregion

    //region mustOverride
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        oyente.onClickSpanText(this);
    }
    //endregion

    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
        ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
    }
}
```

and finally, in the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
  implements IClickSpannableListener{

  public void onClickSpanText(SpecialClickableSpan sender) {
    System.out.println(sender.getText());
    switch (sender.getText()){
      case "50 pence": //do something
        break;
      //...
      case else:
      //....
  }

    private void setSpannableWords(String wordsWithToken){
        wordsWithToken="   50 pence   front page   massive   There's a history   "; //for this example
            //IMPORTANT between «50» and «pence»,  «front» and «page», and also between «there's» and «a» and «history»
            //THERE ISN'T space (asc 32), there is ALT+255. This avoid wordwrap in those texts
        SpannableString spannableString=new SpannableString(wordsWithToken);
        int inicio=wordsWithToken.indexOf(" ")+3;
        while (inicio>2){
            int fin=wordsWithToken.indexOf(" ",inicio);
            if (fin>-1){
                SpecialClickableSpan specialClickableSpan=new SpecialClickableSpan(wordsWithToken.substring(inicio,fin),this,true);
                spannableString.setSpan(specialClickableSpan, inicio, fin, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                spannableString.setSpan(specialClickableSpan.getRoundedBackgroundSpan(), inicio, fin, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                inicio=fin;
            }
            inicio=wordsWithToken.indexOf(" ",inicio+2)+1;
        }
        TextView textView=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvWordText));
        if (textView.getMovementMethod()==null) {
            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        textView.setText(spannableString);
    }


}
```

and this is the result:
[image]

Edit: Sorry, I forgot RoundedBackgroundSpan class. Here is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.text.style.ReplacementSpan;


public class RoundedBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    private static int CORNER_RADIUS = 8;
    private int backgroundColor = Color.CYAN;
    private int textColor = Color.BLACK;

    public RoundedBackgroundSpan() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        if (top==0){
            top=4;
        }
        top+=2;
        RectF rect = new RectF(x-3, top, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end)+3, bottom);
        paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS, paint);
        paint.setColor(textColor);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    }

    private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
        return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` is designed to only allow one row/column of items. If you want the row-wrapping behavior you describe, you can create a custom [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) implementation, or use a third-party library like https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

If those buttons represent a collection of similar objects that are interacted with in a uniform manner, then a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) should work as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to create a custom viewGroup